# Dynamic alignment in ActionScript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'd like to be able to press a button and get a set of movie clips arranged in a row, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is really a general question. I suppose you are placing your AS code inside frames. If that's the case you should have all MovieClips available by their names. So if we pretend that you already have a collection of clips you would like to align:

```
var desiredRowYposition = 100;
buttonMc.onClick = function() {
   for (var mc in mcCollection) {
       mcCollection[mc]._y = desiredRowYposition;
   }
}
```